# Reading a binary file into 2D array python

Tags: python, numpy

I am having trouble reading a binary file in python and plotting it. It is supposedly an unformatted binary file representing a 1000x1000 array of integers. I have used:

```
image = open("file.dat", "r")
a = np.fromfile(image, dtype=np.uint32)
```

Printing the length returns 500000. I cannot figure out how to create a 2D array out of it.

Comment: If it is binary you should open it with `rb`

Answer (score 4):

Since you are getting half a million `uint32`s using

```
a = np.fromfile(image, dtype=np.uint32)
```

then you will get a million `uint16`s using

```
a = np.fromfile(image, dtype=np.uint16)
```

There are other possibilities, however. The dtype could be any 16-bit integer dtype such as

- `>i2` (big-endian 16-bit signed int), or
- `<i2` (little-endian 16-bit signed int), or
- `<u2` (little-endian 16-bit unsigned int), or
- `>u2` (big-endian 16-bit unsigned int).

`np.uint16` is the same as either `<u2` or `>u2` depending on the endianness of your machine.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(np.iinfo(np.uint16).max, size=(1000,1000)).astype(np.uint16)
arr.tofile('/tmp/test')
arr2 = np.fromfile('/tmp/test', dtype=np.uint32)
print(arr2.shape)
# (500000,)

arr3 = np.fromfile('/tmp/test', dtype=np.uint16)
print(arr3.shape)
# (1000000,)
```

Then to get an array of shape (1000, 1000), use reshape:

```
arr = arr.reshape(1000, 1000)
```